# How to update values for all rows having null value | Prisma | Type script | MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, prisma

I have prisma schema like below

```
model t1 {
  id             Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  title          String
  previousNodeId Int?            @unique
}
```

and I wanted to update title of rows who have `null` values in `previousNodeId`

I have written query

```
await prisma.t1.update({
        where: { previousNodeId: null },
        data: {
            title:"update title"
        }
    });
```

but I am not able to update it.
Getting error `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.`

`The expected type comes from property 'previousNodeId' which is declared here on type 'T1WhereUniqueInput'`

I am able to get all rows using `findMany`.

```
await prisma.t1.findMany({
        where: { previousNodeId: null },
    
    });
```

**Result of `findMany`**

```
[
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'demo t1 1',
    previousNodeId: null
  }
]
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `updateMany`?

Comment: no. only `update` because at the time of query execution, table will have only one row having `previousNodeId` `null`

Comment: Yes, but you still have to use `updateMany` because there could *potentially* be more than one `null` row. You can only use `update` when it is guaranteed to only update one row, which is not the case here.